# Variance in package between me and another colleague in a new company

Tags: salary, new-job, human-resources, negotiation

I have got an offer from a company named "A". My friend working in company "B", also got an offer from the same company, "A". We both have the same years of experience and similar background.

However, during the salary discussion, my friend was offered USD $700 more than me per annum. But when the HR discussed with me, he said, that was the best salary he could offer me.

How could this disparity be? Is the HR cheating me? Is there any way to go about this?

Myself and my colleague both that the same years of experience, same relevant work experience. But we both studied at different universities. Will this bring about a difference in salary?

Years of experience is 3+ years.

Comment: Did the HR cheat me when he said that that was the best he could offer me, but gave more to my friend despite having almost the same relevant experience ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere OP may not be in the US. Depending on their location the $13.50 weekly difference could be significant.

Comment: It doesn't have to be HR. It could just be the hiring manager that told HR, I really like this guy, he supports the same basketball team than I do, make sure you get him for us. Or this guy is ok, he's a bit on the quiet side, but he'll do I suppose.

Comment: 700$/y Δ isn't really significant, maybe his tactics during salary discussions were just a bit better, and he was able to convince company 'A' that he's worth the annual salary..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What others are offered, is no business to you, what matters is: **are you getting paid as much as you think you are worthy of?**

Ask yourself:  are **you** happy with the package and the benefits **you** are getting? Do you believe you are getting paid of your market worth?

- If yes, go ahead with the package and plan.
- If no, either try to renegotiate or look elsewhere.

Do not make your decisions based on what other are getting. Ask yourself this question: If you would have found out your friend was getting $700 less than you, would you approach HR to lessen your package?

---

To cite some possible reasons for the difference (this is guess work, we don't know the exact reason, whatsoever):

- Assignment to different business group / team
- Fulfilling some different position / requirement
- Other individual negotiations

But once again, it really does not matter.

Comment: What others are offered is "market rate" and as such it's very much extremely important business to you if you want to be paid well. Information asymmetry benefits the employer, not the employee.

Answer (score 2):

There is the experience and so on that you have on paper, and there's what you did in your job interview. That interview can be absolutely crucial. The most recent interview that I got involved in, we looked a bit at official qualifications, but we looked a lot at how the person acted. My impression was that if there was some problem doing the job, he would go and solve it. That he wouldn't need any hand holding. Fortunately I was right. And that kind of impression will change how much money the company offers.

So it seems that your friend made a $700p.a. better impression in his job interview than you did.

Alternatively, you may be working in different departments, of which one is more successful and therefore can pay its employees better salaries. Or they have different managers, one less tight than the other financially. Even in that case, often the department willing/able to pay more would have the first pick.